# List parameter in pyodbc prepared statement

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, prepared-statement, pyodbc

I am trying to create a prepared statement with the following pattern:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE key IN (value1, value2, value3, ..., valueN)
```

With pyodbc I tried the following syntax:

```
values = set(...)
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table WHERE key IN (?)', values)
```

Error:

```
The SQL contains <N> paramter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied
```

Do I have to generate a `(?, ?, <...>, ?)` for N ? myself or can I somehow insert a list/set into a single field of a prepared statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to bind a list/set/collection to a `?` placeholder which can only receive a single scalar value.  One option here is to build a dynamic `WHERE key IN (?,?,?)` clause based on the length of the list:

```
values = [value1, value2, value3, ...]
query = '(?' + ', ?' * (len(values) - 1) + ')'
sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE key IN ' + query
cursor.execute(sql)
```

The key point here is that if the number of `?` placeholders match the size of the list you are trying to bind, then it works.

Comment: Looks good. I would implement this with a string join instead of the way you did, but that certainly works. I was just wondering if there is a more elegant solution, which does not require any preprocessing

Comment: Well you could certainly define your own function or package which implements the above.  You are limited by the prepare statement API of your database; it isn't really a Python thing.

Comment: I decided to just do it like this.